# T-SQL Extract portion of xml or nvarchar(max) column matching pattern

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to do something that I think is fairly trivial using T-SQL//SQL Server 2008 R2, but I can't seem to figure out a way.

**If I were in Java, C#, C++, whatever, I would do:**

1. Find position of first occurrance of '123' in string
2. Execute substring operation from that position getting next 50 characters

**So, in SQL Server, I'd basically like:**

1. Find all rows where column (X) contains said string (basically a
   LIKE clause)
2. Return 50 characters from that column starting at the said string's location.

*Can I do this somehow?*  I can cast an XML column to nvarchar(max), do a like operation, and do a substring operation, I don't know how to get the position of the said string in the column in the first place though.

---

***Sample content requested in comment***

`CREATE TABLE SampleTable(xmlData xml);`

Pretend the value is in one if SampleTable's xmlData column is as follows.  I would like to, for debugging purposes, extract the string from the funny unicode `Þ` character forward 50 characters (or to the end of the file if that's less than 50).

```
<RootNode>
    <Row>
        <NestedNode1>
            some text.
        </NestedNode1>

        <NestedNode2>
            123456
        </NestedNode2>

        <NestedNode3>
            Þ Some crazy name with unicode letters. Þ
        </NestedNode3>
    </Row>
</RootNode>
```

---

Comment: Can you give an example of the source data and match pattern? As this is XML there may well be some XML method to do what you need more correctly than casting to string and using `CHARINDEX` / `PATINDEX`

Comment: Why doesn't SUBSTRING(X,CHARINDEX('123',X),50) do what you want?

Comment: Sure, not a problem.  I ammended the question above with a sample.

Comment: @GilM, maybe it does - post it as the answer and if CHARINDEX works I'll be a happy man and you'll get points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for CHARINDEX?

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CAST (xmlData as nvarchar(max)) as X
    FROM SampleTable
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(X,CHARINDEX(N'Þ',X),50) as [String]
FROM CTE
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'Þ',X)>0
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Not sure how I missed charindex in my googling :) but I'm happy it's that simple.

Comment: No problem.  It's good to be happy.  Some things are hard to google.